# "TTL OUT" on PCB

Tags: pcb, ttl, reverse-engineering

I was wondering what this TTL OUT means and what type of cable it takes.

I think it might take a display or a camera but unsure.

[image]

Comment: It probably takes an FFC cable, and other than the fact that the signal levels are probably TTL, and it's probably mostly an output, there's no way of knowing what it does.  A closer, end-on, shot of the connector itself may help with the "what cable" part.

Comment: TTL means the threshold is 1.3 V like 74HCT’ family

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - Classic TTL doesn't have a single threshold. A low input must be less than 0.8 volts, and a high input greater than 2 volts for specified noise margin - a couple of chips with Schmitt triggers excepted, of course, and they don't have a single threshold, either. Assuming 0.4 volts noise margin, this implies nominal thresholds of 1.2 and 1.6 volts.

Comment: This PCB is an lcd to hdmi adapter. It’s currently connected via hdmi to an old laptop screen. I saw the “TTL OUT” and was curious about its uses. It looks like a 40 pin display output but not completely sure.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I disagree. All TTL floats the input at just above this threshold for a “1” and the 0.8, 2V is for power noise margin on crosstalk,    the voltage levels margins are a system spec by design. The BJT drift is only -2.4mV/‘C on this threshold approx. and the current gain is 10. This is by design and has always been true since 74,74L,74LS,74S and all RS-232 which use bipolar margins +/-3 to 15V since impedance is higher

Comment: 7400 started with a threshold of 2 Vbe drops  of 0.6V on the input, yet is never specified.

Comment: But the 1.3V threshold @Tony mentioned is a very "soft" threshold.  It's not like a high speed comparator.  If you design a TTL/S/LS circuit that operates with an input between (say)  0.8V and 2.0V, you would just be asking for trouble.

Comment: @SteveSh If  you could guarantee a driver  design for those levels of 0.8V max, it will always be logic "0" and 2.0V will always be a logic  "1"  "Guaranteed!  but then if you have crosstalk and ringing, then it may not be those levels.  With a resistor pullup you can get a full swing with an input swing of 200mVpp around threshold which will change slightly with fan-out and/or pull-up.. Pullup is not needed unless you need >4.5 V swing  for some analog reason.  Yes it's soft  but so were unbuffered CD4000 series on 5V with a gain of 10

Comment: OK I guess I have to prove my point.   https://tinyurl.com/yghcfl4n   p4 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls04.pdf

Comment: "Can get a full swing" is not the same thing as "guaranteeing a full swing" (with an input swing of 200mVpp around threshold).  I assume you're talking out the output voltage swing.

Answer (score 2):

Older displays supported a parallel TTL-level digital interface: R,G,B of between 3 to 8 bits each, HS, VS, and clock. Newer ones support LVDS and other serialized standards.

More here: https://www.digitalview.com/blog/lcd-panel-interfaces-a-quick-guide/